# typescript - how can I dynamically access the elements of an object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have several fields with data:

```
<input
    type="text"
    placeholder={`title`}
    onChange={(e) => change(`title`,e)}
/>
<input
    type="text"
    placeholder={`description`}
    onChange={(e) => change(`description`,e)}
/>
...
```

and only 1 state for all of them:

```
type Iinfo = {
  title: string,
  description: string,
  stars: number
}
const [info, setInfo] = useState<Iinfo | null>(null)
```

I want that when the user enters something into the fields in the state, only the corresponding field is overwritten

```
const change = (title: string,e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
   setInfo ({...info,[title]:e.target.value})
}
```

but typescript gives an error:
[image]

how can I get the results I want without creating something like:

```
interface A {
  [key: string]: string;
  [key: number]: string;
}
```

Comment: You can provide a default value, like `setInfo({...info, title: e.target.value ?? ""})`, or wrap that whole block in an if statement to ensure that the value of `e.target.value` is never undefined. I'm not familiar with the syntax you have in the expression `[title]:e.target.value`, I think putting the title prop in square brackets `[]` is probably a mistake

Comment: but if I remove the square brackets, only the title field will change.... and thanks to square brackets it is possible to set the field to be changed in input

Comment: `e.target.value` is a string, but one of those values is a `number`. That will take some runtime conversion so you have to know what you are setting. This seems like a bad approach.

Comment: IMHO you should just `onChange={(e) => setInfo({ ...info, title: e.target.value })}`. It's hard to generically have an update function like this when the value types aren't consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed the initial state from null to an empty object object and the error disappeared

```
const [info, setInfo] = useState<Iinfo>({
  title: '',
  description: '',
  stars: 0
})
```

I don't quite understand how it works I would be very grateful if you could explain it to me

Answer (score 0):

Input is likely to provide type undefined in certain cases, you can do

```js
const change = (title: string,e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
   setInfo ({...info,[title]:e.target.value || ""})
}
```

adding

```js
|| ""
```

will pass an empty string if the value of e.target.value is undefined, solving the type problem

Comment: my code editor is still trumpeting the error... but thanks for trying.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).